# I'm building an API and I'm facing problems with comparing arrays

Tags: php

**I have two array into it arrays like this**
**I have tried to use array unique and array merge but something goes wrong **
I have tried to do that in mysql and I founded no way by my side
please refer me to best way to do that and explain to me why

```
"ads_view": [
    {
        "ads_view_id": 2,
        "ads_view_userID": "dA9sBwE4OVgT3kvwgqragJ3NYYW2",
        "ads_view_adsID": 1,
        "ads_id": 1,
        "ads_desc": "bee",
        "ads_type": "video",
        "ads_link": "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api- 
  docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4",
        "ads_points": 0
    },
    {
        "ads_view_id": 3,
        "ads_view_userID": "dA9sBwE4OVgT3kvwgqragJ3NYYW2",
        "ads_view_adsID": 2,
        "ads_id": 2,
        "ads_desc": "something",
        "ads_type": "video",
        "ads_link": "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/asse...",
        "ads_points": 0
    },
    {
        "ads_view_id": 4,
        "ads_view_userID": "dA9sBwE4OVgT3kvwgqragJ3NYYW2",
        "ads_view_adsID": 3,
        "ads_id": 3,
        "ads_desc": "something",
        "ads_type": "video",
        "ads_link": "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/asse...",
        "ads_points": 0
    }
]
}

{
"adss": [
    {
        "ads_id": 1,
        "ads_desc": "bee",
        "ads_type": "video",
        "ads_link": "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4",
        "ads_points": 20
    },
    {
        "ads_id": 2,
        "ads_desc": "something",
        "ads_type": "video",
        "ads_link": "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/asse...",
        "ads_points": 30
    },
    {
        "ads_id": 3,
        "ads_desc": "something",
        "ads_type": "video",
        "ads_link": "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/asse...",
        "ads_points": 30
    },
    {
        "ads_id": 4,
        "ads_desc": "something",
        "ads_type": "video",
        "ads_link": "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/asse...",
        "ads_points": 30
    },
    {
        "ads_id": 5,
        "ads_desc": "something",
        "ads_type": "video",
        "ads_link": "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/asse...",
        "ads_points": 30
    }
]
}
```

**what I need just two result **

> ***result one  matching arrays***
>
> ***result two  not matching arrays***

**NOTE: my code PHP
Thanks**

```
 $result = $ads_view->read_multiple();

  // get the row count 
 $ads_viewNum = $result->rowCount();
 if($ads_viewNum > 0 ){
     $ads_view_arr = array();
     $ads_view_arr['ads_view'] = array();
     while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
         extract($row);
             $ads_view_array = array(
             'ads_view_id'           => $ads_view_id,
             'ads_view_userID'       => $ads_view_userID,
             'ads_view_adsID'        => $ads_view_adsID,
             'ads_id'                => $ads_id,
             'ads_desc'              => $ads_desc,
             'ads_type'              => $ads_type,
             'ads_link'              => $ads_link,
             'ads_points'            => 0
             );
             array_push($ads_view_arr['ads_view'], $ads_view_array);
         
     }
     // convert to JSON and output
      echo json_encode($ads_view_arr);

 $ads = new ads($db);
    
    $result = $ads->read();
    $ads_arr = array();
    $ads_arr['adss'] = array();

   while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       extract($row);
       $ads_item = array(
           'ads_id'                => $ads_id,
           'ads_desc'               => $ads_desc,
           'ads_type'               => $ads_type,
           'ads_link'               => $ads_link,
           'ads_points'             => $ads_points

       );
       array_push($ads_arr['adss'], $ads_item);
   }
   // convert to JSON and output
     echo json_encode($ads_arr);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "matching"? what part of the array should match what exactly?

Comment: I need to comparing with ads_id From (adss)  and  ads_view_adsID From (ads_view) if this matching I need all records into this object in matching array and the other I need them into Not matching array

Comment: For Example  i need ads_id = 4 and ads_id = 5 in lets call array : Not matching or not existing array but i want all record that's belong to this IDs

Comment: Still very unclear to me. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).